# Is there a good place to learn Sword or War Glove moves?

Tags: absolver

After becoming an Absolver, I was sent back to Adal to continue my training. I've learned 50-60 bare fist moves, but I have learned a whopping total of **0** war glove and sword moves, due to the fact that these break very quickly. I very rarely encounter enemies with swords and I've yet to see a single regular enemy using war gloves.

Is there a location I can go to reliably fight enemies with swords or war gloves so that I can expand my movesets for these weapons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost positive wargloves use the same moveset as bare-handed, just adding damage and effectively swapping combat decks mid-fight, which could confuse an opponent who has your regular deck figured out.

As for learning sword moves off AI, you have to get familiar with sword spawn locations in each area; I think there's usually about 4-5 per area. Find an enemy (mini-bosses included), bring them a sword (or gather a bunch of swords), and block/dodge, kill and repeat. Wearing high cut protection armor could help with some of the tougher ones to mitigate chip damage while you block. Figure out how to identify different enemy types (they usually have a specific piece of gear in common with 2-3 variations each) and keep in mind each one you've learned everything from. If an enemy you don't want picks up a sword before you get to it, you can try to smack them around til they drop it or skip that sword. Some of the weakest enemies won't pick up swords. I recommend playing offline or solo invitation mode because swords respawn on death, but it can be weird with other players around picking them up and such.

All the mini-bosses should also start with a sword after a certain level, except for Dormek (the one in Tower of Adal) who won't use swords. Jinn (and a couple of the harder regular enemies) will pull out his own after you smack him around a bit and if you fight him in the Hunting Path, he spawns next to one.

Source: Learned all but 3 sword moves off AI. If you can, learn from other players instead. It can take a while off AI, especially if you mess up and die occasionally.

Good luck and happy hunting!